# Nested virtualization on Azure Lab Services

Tags: windows, nested, hyper-v, azure-lab-services

Is it possible to create one Windows Server 2019 LAB Machine where I run 3-4 VMs on Hyper-v? Is it supported + what about licensing of e.g Windows 10 running there.
Is it possible to configure virtual switches like in on-premise environment?

Comment: What part of this involves the [`vms`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vms/info) family of operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

But, the machines size is limited unless you upgraded to pay-as-you-go subscription. In general the guest OS license is bring your own.

Under hyper-v, there are some windows guest machines but it uses up over 40GB of the azure lab machines. I don't think you can create more than 1 nested windows machines.

Answer (score -1):

In the context of Azure Lab Services, yes it is possible to run Hyper-V client VMs on your template and lab VMs. When using Hyper-V in Azure Lab Services it is important to remember.

1. To choose a size that supports nested virtualization.
2. To 'prepare' the host machine to use Hyper-V including installing necessary windows feature and creating a NAT network. See [how to enable nested virtualization on template VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-template-vm).
3. OS disk size is limited to 128 GB.  If you find space getting tight, see [Nested Virtualization Tips and Tricks](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-lab-services/nested-virtualization-tips/ba-p/1534323) which covers tricks like switching to using VHDX and using dynamic memory.

There are some example classes that you might find helpful. The [Ethical Hacking class template](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/lab-services/class-type-ethical-hacking) using nested virtualization to have Metasploitable and Kali Linux client VMs on the same NAT network. There is also a [Networking with GNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/lab-services/class-type-networking-gns3) example class that shows you how to use GNS3 to virtualize and test on-premise type networking environments.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer instead of linking to external ressources

Comment: As requested, I've added clarification to the answer as well as a quick explanation of what the links cover.  All links are to official Microsoft documentation of official Azure Lab Services blog.